# Issue Installing TensorFlow on Windows 11 with Python 3.12.0

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I am facing an issue while trying to install TensorFlow on my Windows 11 machine with Python 3.12.0 and pip 23.2.1 (64-bit). Despite several attempts, I keep receiving the following error messages:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I have tried creating virtual environments using both Python 3.7.0 and Python 3.6.4

cleared the pip cache using the command `pip cache purge`

Install TensorFlow with various specific versions

`tensorflow==2.1.0`

`tensorflow==2.5.0`

`tensorflow==2.2.0rc4`

I hoping anyone know what might be the issue here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tensorflow currently support python 3.11 so try downgrading your python edition it should work and try to follow the instructions on tf website for tf installation using pip it contains detailed information, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, your idea worked : set version 3.9 and it work !
Tensorflow web site speak about the following compatibility : Python 3.6 – 3.9.

@Krishna, would you validate the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue , I installed it successfully by pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

try pip install tensorflow-gpu it should work

Comment: I really thought that you tried a different post, with more helpful formatting or at least a helpful newline between code and prose. You did not even try. Seeing that you did not even take the [tour] I worry that you won't bother with helpful information on that, but nevertheless, here it is: [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Ideally add a description of the effect of what you propose and an explanation of why you expect it to help with the problem described at the top of the page.

Comment: Obviously OP already tried that and had issues with specific versions ;)

Comment: You seem to be trying to delete your post. For that, as an unregistered user, you need to first register - or flag your own post for moderator attention and ask to have it deleted. Vandalising your own post however is not tolderated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).